# tail -f, but only every 1000th row

Tags: linux, bash, tail

```
tail -f myfile.log
```

is very nice, but if you have a big file you may only want to display **every nth row**.

So the output will show row 1, row 1001, row 2001 and so on.

Is this possible or do the output needs to be chained into `sed`, `awk` or something else?

Comment: The streaming nature of the `tail -f` command is important here. If you solve the problem with `awk`, as the accepted solution does, before adding other commands to the pipe after `awk`, you may want to flush the output in the `awk` command. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33650/why-does-awk-do-full-buffering-when-reading-from-a-pipe or https://superuser.com/questions/379122/how-to-pipe-awk-output-with-periodic-continuous-input-to-output-file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR%1000==1'
```

Sample every 3rd:

```
$ seq 1 10 | awk 'NR%3==1'
1
4
7
10
```

Comment: `seq -w 10000 | awk 'NR%1000==1'` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below command to get it

```
$> seq 1 4000 | awk 'NR%1000-1==0' # or awk 'NR%1000==1'
1
1001
2001
3001

$> seq 1 4000  >> file
$> cat file |   awk 'NR%1000-1==0'
1
1001
2001
3001

$> tail -f -n 40000 file  | awk 'NR%1000-1==0'                                                                                                                                                  (2.6.3)
1
1001
2001
3001
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
seq 1 4000 | sed -nu '1~1000p'
```

Output:

```
1
1001
2001
3001
```